# zend mail giving mail in unreadable format when using in magento

Tags: magento, zend-mail

Used the following code.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml($message)
->setFrom('abc@gty.com', 'abc')
->addTo($to, 'admin')
->setSubject($subj);
```

This is the part i wrote.

I am getting proper html in `$message`. The $ variable used above are from retrieved post value. The mail which I am receiving contains contents like :

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

in the starting part rest all the mail content are fine.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From myunderstanding,i conclude with this part `utf-8` adding in your code

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setBodyHtml($message)
->setFrom('abc@gty.com', 'abc')
->addTo($to, 'admin')
->setSubject($subj);
```

Hope this helps you.